# simulink model of wind turbine lqg regulation does not work properly

Tags: matlab, simulink, turbine

I have simulated the following block diagram with consists of a wind turbine state space with kalman filter, full state feedback and full state observer suggested by an article which I uploaded:

[image: block diagram with consists of a wind turbine state space with kalman filter, full state feedback and full state observer]

I don't know why I don't get the same output as the article!  This is my simulink simulation:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b6pJ.png)
The wind speed in my simulation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L54N0.png)
This is my output:

[image: my output]

This is the output in the article:

[image: output in the article]

Also I'm not sure about where should I put the wind speed? I would really appreciate if you could help.

This is my simulink file:
https://easyupload.io/6oo280

This is the article:
https://easyupload.io/4gxnt6

Comment: You've shown one unlabelled plot vs 3 plots, are you driving the sim with the same input speed? Can you add a scope to show that?

Comment: actually x is a state vector in which x1 is rotor speed, x2 generator speed and x3 generator speed. and yes I am using the same wind speed. The article has mentioned: "For the sake of simplicity, both turbine and measurement noises were assumed to have the same magnitude as the wind but in the case of turbine system noise, it was scaled by the matrix G.". I am wondering if the block diagram the article suggested as kalamn bucy filter is correct or not?